# Using index of parent on child in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Updated to include a link to the full code: https://bl.ocks.org/tgerard/d8711d6582e082e0f3818a03879f896e

I'm making a vis that has columns and rows of rectangles as per this image (but with correct widths for each rect):
[image]

My trouble is in setting the widths of the rects. They all need to be a little different (the values of 'sluiceWidth' below). I have the widths in a var but I need to access the index of the parent to use it.

My data looks like this (in part):

```
"lock": [
  ["EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR"],
  ["EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR"],
  ["EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR"],
  ["EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR"],
  ["EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR"],
  ["EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR"],
  ["EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR"],
  ["EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR"],
  ["EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR"],
  ["EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR"],
  ["EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR"],
  ["EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR"],
  ["EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR"],
  ["EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR"],
  ["EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR"],
  ["EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY", "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR"],
  ["EMPTY", "EMPTY", "ONE", "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR",  "FOUR"]
],
"sluiceWidths": [5.458, 4.900, 4.896, 4.898, 4.849, 4.645, 4.958, 4.959, 5.365, 5.810, 5.810, 5.795, 5.796, 5.793, 5.802, 5.775, 5.804],
```

I'm making a series of g elements with the 'sluiceWidth' data and then using .each to add the 'lock' data as rects in the gs. Here's the relevant code:

```
var lefts = [0];
var rectStart = 0;

    for ( var n = 0; n < lockData.sluiceWidths.length - 1 ; n = n + 1 ) {
        rectStart = rectStart + lockData.sluiceWidths[n];
        lefts.push(rectStart);
    };

var rectLeft = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(lefts);


    svg.selectAll('.bay')
      .data(lockData.lock)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'bay')
      .attr('width', (function (d, i) { return x(rectWidth(i)); }))
      .attr('transform', (function (d, i) { return 'translate(' + x(rectLeft(i)) * 1.1 + ',0)'; }))
      .each(logjam);


    function logjam(d) {
          d3.select(this)
            .selectAll('rect')
            .data(d)
            .enter()
            .append('rect')
            .attr('class', (function (d) { return 'log ' + d; }))
            .attr('width', (function (d, i, j) { return x(rectWidth(j)); }))
            .attr('height', 20)
            .attr('x', 0)
            .attr('y', (function (d, i) { return i * 24; }))
        };
```

The issue is with the fourth last line, where I want to set the widths – I can't seem to access the index numbers of the g elements – it's only accessing the first one and applying it to all.

Note that I can set the widths of the g elements a little earlier in the code, so there are two ways this might be solved:

1. Access the parent element's index on each iteration.
2. Access the width attribute of the parent and apply that (rather less elegant).

I can put up the full code if desired, but the question's already pretty long.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, create a (non) working jsfiddle/plunker/codepen/whatever... that way, we can actually propose solutions (right now there are some functions you didn't paste, so it's difficult testing anything).

Comment: Hi Gerardo, 

Thanks for your interest. I've added a link at the top of the question to the current version.

Comment: Before I write an answer, is this what you want? https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/9ed43ff473387ff1183f18d1a2ed141c

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it. A thousand thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the index of each group to your `logjam` function:

```
.each(function(d, i) {
    logjam(d, i, this)
});
```

Then, you change `logjam` to:

```
function logjam(data, index, elem) {
    d3.select(elem)
        .selectAll('rect')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', (function(d) {
            return 'log ' + d;
        }))
        .attr('width', (function() {
            return x(rectWidth(index));
        }))
        .attr('height', 20)
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', (function(d, i) {
            return i * 24;
        }))
};
```

here is the updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/9ed43ff473387ff1183f18d1a2ed141c